# JS XMLHttpRequest to PHP Page to Execute MSSQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with an XMLHttpRequest. Basically, an HTML button makes a call to the deleteItem function, which then makes a call to the other function. Each of these two functions makes the XHR to a php page in order to remove tuples from two different database tables.

Here's the code (variables renamed to generics):

JS:

```
//remove first item from first table
function deleteItem() {
    var conn = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var query = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID = " + arrayOfObjects[i][0] + ";";
    conn.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            deleteWorkflowProcess(arrayOfObjects[i][1], conn.responseText);
        }
    }

    conn.open("GET","../../db_query/sql.php?q=" + query + "&p=DELETE", true);
    conn.send();

}

//remove other items from other table
function deleteWorkflowProcess(s, r) {
    var conn = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var query = "DELETE FROM MyOtherTable WHERE FOREIGN_KEY = '" + s + "';";

    if (r == "Deletion succeeded.") {
        conn.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var response = conn.responseText;
                alert(response);
                window.location.replace("thissamepage.php");
            }
        }

        conn.open("GET","../../db_query/sql.php?q=" + query + "&p=DELETE", true);
        conn.send();
    } else {
        alert(r);
    }
}
```

And here's the PHP page that it makes its two calls to:

```
//set up connection
$serverName = "SERVER\MSSQLINSTANCE";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"DATABASE");

if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])) {

    //establish connection
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if ($conn) {

        //delete data
        if ($_REQUEST['p'] == "DELETE") {
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $_REQUEST['q']);
            if ($result) {
                echo "Deletion succeeded.";
            } else {
                echo "Deletion failed: " . explode("]",sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message'])[3];
            }
        }

        //do some other stuff based on 'p' value
        //e.g. insert, update, etc.
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```

Here's what I know for sure:

- The queries are phrased correctly and have no syntax errors.
- The queries are calling the correct tables.
- The first function works as it should by deleting the correct tuples from the first table.
- The second function fails to delete anything from the second table

My question is: **Why would the first function work correctly, but not the second?**

Edits: 
$_REQUEST['q'] is equal to the SQL Query, in this case "DELETE FROM MyOtherTable WHERE FOREIGN_KEY = 'asdf';"

$_REQUEST['p'] is the SQL command I'm using, in this case "DELETE".

sqlsrv_errors() returns nothing, because it's never being called. Near as I can tell, the query executes successfully, it's just that nothing happens. How I know this:

- I know the XHR passes successfully, because the IE developer tools Network tab says this: 
  sql.php?q=SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable WHERE FOREIGN_KEY = 'asdf';&p=SELECT
- The above GET gives a status 200 code.
- If it had failed, JS would pop an alert that said "Deletion failed" and then would give the error. Instead, it pops an alert that says "Deletion succeeded", which only happens if the query succeeds, and thus sqlsrv_errors() is not called.

At the suggestion of Zhorov, I've put in sqlsrv_rows_affected() to determine exactly what is happening. It seems that the same number of affected rows is reported each time, regardless of how many rows match the condition in the SQL statement, or even if there are any rows to affect. This behavior only occures in Internet Explorer. In Chrome, both functions behave as they should.

**Major Edit**:
It looks like the scope of this problem has changed. By temporarily disabling caching in IE, I've been able to run both files as intended, with no errors. I'm not sure why IE decided to cache it, but the question now has become **what can be done to the program to disable or work around the caching in IE?** I can hardly expect every user to do this themselves.

Comment: What does sqlsrv_errors() return? And can you post then $_REQUEST['q'] value? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me this is just a pseudo code/example that you're not trying to push on production server - having php script that takes `sql` from `http GET` and executes it directly in DB? Without escapeing? That's like yelling "_please steal all my data and delete all my tables_". Move sql to php script and pass only ID's of items that need to be deleted (and escape them please)

Comment: @Michal Bieda Thanks for your concern. I'm aware of the problems with SQL injection. This will be production, but is nowhere near that point yet. At the moment, I'm working function. There's not even any real data in the DB yet, so there's no worries about somebody stealing anything. Don't worry: SQL injection will be covered at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest something, that may help you. Your DELETE statement executes, but does not delete rows, because there are no rows that match WHERE condition.
It is not clear what are your table definitions and what is the actual data (I suppose that 'asdf' is just an example), but I had similar test case and this was a solution.

Check the number of rows modified by the last statement executed with `sqlsrv_rows_affected()`. 
Just put one additional line in your script:

```
...
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $_REQUEST['q']);
if ($result) {
    echo 'Rows affected: '.sqlsrv_rows_affected($result).'</br>';
    echo "Deletion succeeded.";
} else {
    echo "Deletion failed: " . explode("]",sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message'])[3];
}
...
```

So, if this statement is executed without errors and there are 0 rows affected, then one possible reason may be the fact, that FOREIGN_KEY column seems to be of type varchar/nvarchar/text. 
If values in FOREIGN_KEY column contains any special characters, you have to consider the encoding issues when you pass this DELETE statement.

This also will explain the fact, that first function work correctly, while the second one fails.
First function deletes records with WHERE condition based on numeric column values, while the second function deletes records with WHERE condition based on text column values.

How to test the statement:

With SQL Server Management Studio and see the result and affected rows.

With your code, just put INSERT statement before the DELETE statement and check again `sqlsrv_rows_affected()`.

```
...
$sql = "INSERT MyOtherTable (FOREIGN_KEY) VALUES ('asdf');"; 
$sql = $sql + $_REQUEST['q'];
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
    echo 'Rows affected: '.sqlsrv_rows_affected($result).'</br>';
    echo "Deletion succeeded.";
} else {
    echo "Deletion failed: " . explode("]",sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message'])[3];
}
...
```

Information about `sqlsrv_rows_affected()` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-rows-affected?view=sql-server-2017).

**Update:**

User information from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php):

If the sql contains INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements, the number of affected rows must be consumed. 
The sqlsrv_query returns a sql cursor that must be read to finish the transaction, if the result is non false. 
This same is valid for sqlsrv_execute. In this case the cursor must be also read using the prepared statement handle.

```
...
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $_REQUEST['q']);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    }
    echo 'Rows affected: '.sqlsrv_rows_affected($result).'</br>';
    echo "Deletion succeeded.";
} else {
    echo "Deletion failed: " . explode("]",sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message'])[3];
}
...
```

Another solution is to place SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the sqlsrv statement and all called procedures, functions and triggers.

```
...
$sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON;"; 
$sql = $sql + $_REQUEST['q'];
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
    echo 'Rows affected: '.sqlsrv_rows_affected($result).'</br>';
    echo "Deletion succeeded.";
} else {
    echo "Deletion failed: " . explode("]",sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message'])[3];
}
...
```

Comment: Good advice, this definitely cleared up a lot. After thorough testing in both IE and Chrome, I've determined that it only works in Chrome. In IE, it is consistently telling me that 5 rows were affected, despite the fact that there are no rows that match the condition. In Chrome, this behavior does not occur.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that despite it saying 5 rows were affected, no rows are deleted, regardless of how many there are that match the condition.

Comment: @MaclainAnderson Updated answer.

Comment: I tried reading the statement cursor before the echo lines, but it still did nothing. As above, it said 5 rows were affected (there were only 2 that could have been), but nothing was deleted.

Comment: @MaclainAnderson What about SET NOCOUNT ON ?

Comment: No real change. It now says -1 rows affected, which your link says should only be returned when there's no available information on how many rows were affected. This could be because of SET NOCOUNT ON, but I'm not sure. In any case, the rows are still not deleted.

Comment: Instead of using the XHR, I typed the GET URL directly into the address bar. This printed the same result to the page, but did actually delete the rows in question. I'm not sure why this deleted the rows when using the XHR did not, especially when the network tab in IE's developer tools says that the GET request was processed successfully.